# Page not found (404) in Django webapp

Tags: html, django, web, django-views, django-templates

Am building a CRM application and thing was going fine until I got this roadblock `Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/leads//update/`

I have tried tweaking the templates and even the view file but to no avail, Here are the views files for the CRUD aspect

```
class LeadListView(ListView):
   template_name = 'lead_list.html'
   queryset = Lead.objects.all()
   context_object_name = 'leads'


class LeadDetailView(DetailView):
   template_name = 'leads/lead_detail.html'
   queryset = Lead.objects.all()
   context_object_name = 'leads'


class LeadCreateView(CreateView):
   template_name = 'leads/lead_create.html'
   form_class = LeadModelForm

   def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('leads:lead_list')


class LeadUpdateView(UpdateView):
   template_name = 'leads/lead_update.html'
   form_class = LeadModelForm
   queryset = Lead.objects.all()

   def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('leads:lead_list')
```

And here is the HTML template for detail view

```
<div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pr-10 lg:py-6 mb-6 lg:mb-0">
            <h2 class="text-sm title-font text-gray-500 tracking-widest">LEAD</h2>
            <h1 class="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-4">{{ leads.first_name }} {{ leads.last_name }}</h1>
            <div class="flex mb-4">
                <a href="{% url 'leads:lead_detail' leads.pk %}" class="flex-grow text-indigo-500 border-b-2 border-indigo-500 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                    Overview
                </a>
                <a class="flex-grow border-b-2 border-gray-300 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                    Reviews
                </a>
                <a href="/leads/{{ lead.pk }}/update/" class="flex-grow border-b-2 border-gray-300 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                    Update Details
                </a>
            </div>
            <p class="leading-relaxed mb-4">Fam locavore kickstarter distillery. Mixtape chillwave tumeric sriracha taximy chia microdosing tilde DIY. XOXO fam inxigo juiceramps cornhole raw denim forage brooklyn. Everyday carry +1 seitan poutine tumeric. Gastropub blue bottle austin listicle pour-over, neutra jean.</p>
            <div class="flex border-t border-gray-200 py-2">
                <span class="text-gray-500">Age</span>
                <span class="ml-auto text-gray-900">{{ lead.age }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex border-t border-gray-200 py-2">
                <span class="text-gray-500">Size</span>
                <span class="ml-auto text-gray-900">Medium</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex border-t border-b mb-6 border-gray-200 py-2">
                <span class="text-gray-500">Quantity</span>
                <span class="ml-auto text-gray-900">4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
                <span class="title-font font-medium text-2xl text-gray-900">$58.00</span>
                <button class="flex ml-auto text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded">Button</button>
                <button class="rounded-full w-10 h-10 bg-gray-200 p-0 border-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 ml-4">
                    <svg fill="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 000-7.78z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is for the update view

```
div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pr-10 lg:py-6 mb-6 lg:mb-0">
            <h2 class="text-sm title-font text-gray-500 tracking-widest">LEAD</h2>
            <h1 class="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-4">{{ leads.first_name }} {{ leads.last_name }}</h1>
            <div class="flex mb-4">
                <a href="{% url 'leads:lead_detail' lead.pk %}" class="flex-grow text-indigo-500 border-b-2 border-indigo-500 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                    Overview
                </a>
                <a class="flex-grow border-b-2 border-gray-300 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                    Reviews
                </a>
                <a href="/leads/{{ lead.pk }}/update/" class="flex-grow border-b-2 border-gray-300 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                    Update Details
                </a>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <a href="{% url 'leads:lead_delete' lead.pk %}" class="mt-3 flex ml-auto text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded">
                Delete
            </a>
        </div>
```

And I found nothing wrong here with the `urls.py` file

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    lead_list, lead_detail, lead_create, lead_update, lead_delete,
    LeadListView, LeadDetailView, LeadCreateView, LeadUpdateView
)

app_name = 'leads'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', LeadListView.as_view(), name='lead_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', LeadDetailView.as_view(), name='lead_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', LeadUpdateView.as_view(), name='lead_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', lead_delete, name='lead_delete'),
    path('create/', LeadCreateView.as_view(), name='lead_create'),
]
```

Below is the link that is broken and where am I trying to get to

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a double slash in your URI. Does http://127.0.0.1:8000/leads/update/ work? If it does, you need to fix the URI in your code. The only other thing I can see, after skimming the code, is that `lead.pk` could be null causing the double slash, so you can try and figure out why that is.

Comment: Even with the single slash, I still get page 404 page not found

Comment: You are mixing the singular `lead` with plural `leads` in the templates and view functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `context_object_name = leads` in your `LeadDetailView`. However, in your detail template, you are referencing the object of interest with `lead`. So, in the URL in your template, `{{ lead.pk }}` won't be rendered correctly since the `lead` variable is not defined.

It seems it will work if you fix the value of `context_object_name`.

About the 404 status code of the response, that's simply because you haven't specified any parameter as the `pk` parameter. So the URL won't match with any of the URL patterns you have specified in your `urls.py` file.

Comment: this worked. Thank you, context_object_name was different from what was rendered in the templates

Comment: You're welcome. :) Also, it would be appreciated if you could upvote my answer or mark it as the selected answer.